# Android studio not generating apk in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

[Result after build apk success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfJ4I.png)

I am having problem in building debug apk from android studio. I have embedded FFMPEG library separately. The issue is no .apk files is generated in **result picture folders**.
I cannot figure out why i am having this problem ?

Comment: did u check whats on the build tab?

Comment: yeah i checked tried everything posted related to solve issue but still can't generate apk file :(

Comment: what is the result of ::  './gradlew assembleDebug'

Comment: I am surprised to see the `libs` under the `build` folder...the `libs` folder should be under the `app` folder and you need to properly map the `libs` folder in your app's `build.gradle` script.

Comment: I solved that issue. if someone is having this problem. Please go to your project folder > app > outputs > apk after building apk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out this option?

> ```
> Select Build -> Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) -> Build APK(s) from the toolbar menu.
> ```

Once the APK build is complete, you will receive a notification on the bottom right corner of your screen. From that notification, select
Locate and you will be led to the APK file location.